# tab item title become invisible after changing design of the page

Tags: android, android-tablayout

After changing my design (changing relative layouts to constraint layout and fixing constraints) my tablayout is still visible but tab items which I added them in the java became invisible (they still visible but title became invisible)

How can I solve this problem?

here is my xml file (I think the problem is here because I didn't change the java code):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".Fragments.GroupeFragment">
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:background="#95210851"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="20"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:src="@drawable/notification_icon"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.8" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/groupename"

        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="68dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:fontFamily="@font/renner_500_medium"
        android:text="Telnet groupe"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#ffff"
        android:textFontWeight="8"
        android:textSize="23sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/getallmembres"

        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:elevation="3dp"
        android:src="@drawable/login_username_icon"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/groupename"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/addtachebyresp"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:background="@drawable/add_icon"
        android:elevation="3dp"
        android:textColor="#FFFF"
        android:textSize="45sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.258"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/getallmembres"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

<androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout">

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#95210851"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        app:tabTextColor="#fff"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.DarkActionBar"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="#D9C8F8" ></com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>

</androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager>


<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/membreRelativel"

    android:layout_width="353dp"
    android:layout_height="445dp"
    android:layout_marginHorizontal="20dp"
    android:layout_marginVertical="60dp"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner_shape_gris"
    android:elevation="20dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <LinearLayout

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:background="#ffff"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="10">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/membresrecycler"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="9"></androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/goto_add_membres"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:background="@drawable/profile_first_layout"
            android:text="Ajouter des membres" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/hideparticipants"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="X"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.952"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/addmembreLayout"
    android:layout_width="307dp"
    android:layout_height="226dp"
    android:layout_marginHorizontal="50dp"
    android:layout_marginVertical="180dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="386dp"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner_shape_gris"
    android:elevation="25dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.24000001">

    <TextView

        android:layout_width="308dp"
        android:layout_height="26dp"
        android:background="#B6B5B5"

        android:fontFamily="@font/mermaid"
        android:text="Ajout d'un membre"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/linearLayout4"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:id="@+id/titleaddmemebre"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:id="@+id/hideaddmembre"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:elevation="2dp"
        android:text="X"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:weightSum="10"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/titleaddmemebre"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/addmembreemail"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:hint="Email" />

        <Button
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:id="@+id/saveaddmembre"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:background="@drawable/profile_first_layout"
            android:text="Ajouter"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"

            android:textColor="#ffff" />

    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

[image]

Comment: <ConstraintLayout has to go on top of everything not third line down

Comment: i have a constraintLayout wich match parent
the second one is for page title and the return Button
after I have my tabLayout 
i will show you a picture

Comment: Look at your top section of code. You combined your Linear Layout and your Constraint Layout because your ID says linear layout. Seperate them. Put constraint layout on top of everything and add the Linear Layout where it needs to go

Comment: I updated the code 
the previous code was incomplete